# Custom intervals on treadmills

Tags: running, treadmill

I have knee and hip problems, so I run intervals. This is just fine when I run outdoors, but it's starting to get cold in Chicago, and within the next month it's going to be dark both before and after work, so I'd like to buy a treadmill.

I've seen machines that have interval programs preset, like hill intervals or weight-loss intervals. I'm looking for one that will let me input my own intervals. Doesn't have to be fancy - I'm looking for a way to set it up as fast interval = 3 minutes @ x mph, slow interval = 1 minute @ y mph; repeat until I hit stop.

Does a treadmill like this exist? I've tried to explain to the salespeople at my local sporting goods store what I mean by custom intervals, and they just keep pointing me to the machines with the preset workouts.

Comment: There are some, such as this one: http://www.lifefitness.com/commercial/cardio/treadmills/elevationseries/95tengage.html Prices look like they range from $3000 and up. My only question is why you want to run intervals when you already have knee/hip problems? But, if it's working for you, guess that's ok. :D

Comment: Why wouldn't I run intervals with knee and hip problems? The slower intervals (which are usually walking) give my joints a break from the pounding they take with the run intervals.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a cross-trainer or elliptical trainer? It causes less impact on the knees than a treadmill. I have weak knees and I really love this exercise. I do it for warming up before weighths, normally 10 minutes, but sometimes I enjoy it so much (together with music) that I just keep going :-)

Comment: I've used ellipticals, yes, but I prefer running. I have yet to see a charity race that's done on ellipticals!

Comment: This answers "How can I do cardio with less impact," but has nothing to do with the questions being asked!